# Why the anti derivative of $\sec(x) \cdot \tan(x)$ is $\sec(x)$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I have discovered that $$\sec(x) = \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$$ but I do not understand why the indefinite integral of $\sec(x) \cdot \tan(x)$ is $\sec(x)$.

I am watching the following videos:

- https://www.khanacademy.org/math/integral-calculus/indefinite-definite-integrals/indefinite_integrals/.

Specifically, I am in the last lecture, doing the exercises.

But the professor, as far I remember, has not talked about these situations.

Comment: What happens when you differentiate $\sec{x}$ with respect to $x$? Remember that $\int f(x) dx = F(x) \iff F'(x) = f(x)$ (that, informally speaking, one should redirect oneself to the [Fundamental theorem of calculus](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalTheoremsofCalculus.html))

Comment: anyone got a geometric version?

Comment: @Miguelgondu Your statement is quite formal seeing as the symbol $\int$ without indices is literally defined as taking a primitive.

Comment: @GPerez The $c$'s missing, though, :)

Answer (score 7):

Lets consider the indefinite integral,

$$ \int \sec(x)\tan(x) dx = \int \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)} dx$$

We can then perform a $u$ substitution with $u=\cos(x)$ and $du = -\sin(x) dx $ obtaining,

$$ \int \sec(x)\tan(x) dx  = -\int \frac{1}{u^2} du= \frac{1}{u} + C = \frac{1}{\cos(x)} +C = \sec(x) + C$$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Here's something for you to think about.

By the Chain Rule  $$\frac{d}{dx} \left(\cos (x)\right)^{-1} = (-1) (\cos (x))^{-2} \dot \, (-\sin (x)) = \frac{1}{\cos x} \dot\, \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$$

**Edit:** In order to find $\int \sec x \tan x dx $. Write it as $$\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2 x}$$

and make the substitution $u = \cos x$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: Substitution, take $u = \cos x$. I'll edit it.

Comment: I *really* don't recommend using $\cos^{-1}(x)$ notation to denote $\cos(x)^{-1}$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Not to confuse with $\arccos x$, right?

Comment: @AaronMaroja Yeah. I avoid using $\operatorname{trig}^{-1}$ notation myself but a lot of people don't.

Comment: @CameronWilliams You just reminded me of when my professor once took a question because of that. It's a matter of context, but I agree with you.

Answer (score 3):

The expression $\sec x\tan x$ can be written
$$
\frac{1}{\cos x}\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2 x}
=-\frac{-\sin x}{\cos^2 x}=-\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2}
$$
where $f(x)=\cos x$. Consider, for a generic differentiable function $f$,
$$
g(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}.
$$
By the chain rule
$$
g'(x)=-\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2}.
$$
In the special case of $f(x)=\cos x$, we see that
$$
g(x)=\frac{1}{\cos x}=\sec x
$$

There's really nothing more than this; it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more elementary way of seeing it from the derivative of $\sec{\theta}$:

$\frac{\sec(\theta+\delta)-\sec\theta}{\delta}=\frac{\frac{1}{\cos(\theta+\delta)}-\frac{1}{\cos\theta}}{\delta}=\frac{cos\theta-\cos(\theta+\delta)}{\delta\cos\theta\cos(\theta+\delta)}$,

So

$\frac{d}{d\theta}(\sec{\theta})=\lim\limits_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sec(\theta+\delta)-\sec\theta}{\delta}=\lim\limits_{\delta\rightarrow 0}-\frac{\cos(\theta+\delta)-\cos\theta}{\delta}\frac{1}{\cos\theta}\frac{1}{\cos(\theta+\delta)}$.

The first term is the (opposite of) the derivative of $\cos\theta$; the other two simply go to $\cos\theta$.

Since $\frac{d}{d\theta}(\cos\theta)=-\sin\theta$, we get the result.

For a nice geometric proof of the derivative of $\sin\theta$ which can easily be adjusted to prove the cosine derivative, see [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-differentiation/part-a-definition-and-basic-rules/session-8-limits-of-sine-and-cosine/MIT18_01SCF10_Ses8d.pdf).