# Is there any Geometric explanation for derivatives of cosecant and cot?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to understand calculus intuitively.so, I am looking for geometric explanation for derivatives of trig functions.Through a stack exchange answer I understand geometric explanation for 4 trig functions but from that answer I couldn't understand cosecant and cot function derivatives. so, please give geometric explanation for cosecant and cot functions specifically.

Comment: See, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299682/geometric-intuition-for-derivatives-of-basic-trig-functions

Comment: Can't you do with the fact that they are inverses of the sine and the tangent ? If you understood the tangent, just swap the axis for the cotangent.

Comment: I can find it using first principle but geometrically it is different from secant tangent triangle.